# How do I Paste an Excel table into word without losing the row heights

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am copying a range from Excel into Word in the following way:

```
Set oRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:V27")
oRng.Copy
objDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteSpecial , , 0
```

This works except that the row heights are changed.

Doing it manually, row heights can be kept with paste special as Microsoft Excel Worksheet Object

[image]

My question is:
Can this be done in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

```
Option Explicit

Const wdPasteOLEObject As Integer = 0
Const wdInLine As Integer = 0

Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    oWordApp.Visible = True
    
    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Add
    
    '~~> Sample range copied
    Sheet1.Range("A1:D10").Copy
    
    oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
                                    DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, _
                                    Placement:=wdInLine, _
                                    DisplayAsIcon:=False
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, _Placement:=wdInLine, _DisplayAsIcon:=False`     This did the trick. Thanks!